# Table Not extending to next Page

Tags: longtable

I used excel2latex plugin to convert my excel table into LaTeX. But the table is long and it is not extending next page when the current page is full. I have installed the `\usepackage{multirow,longtable,bigstrut,caption}`. I tried changing the `\begin{table}` to `\begin{longtable}` but still no positive result. What should I change in my original code below to make it work:

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet '(ALL)'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{TESTING}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|rrrr}
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Seq2}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.69527 & 0.67426 & 0.68460 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.90242} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.89107} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.89671} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textbf{OURS} & \textbf{0.75482} & \textbf{0.75482} & \textbf{0.75482} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.92057}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.91528}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.91792}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq3}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Seq4}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.61123} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.61019} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.61071} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textbf{OURS} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.81705}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.81705}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.81705}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq5}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Seq6}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.87119 & 0.84164 & 0.85616 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.88654} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.88654} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.88654} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textbf{OURS} & \textbf{0.89381} & \textbf{0.89474} & \textbf{0.89427} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.89259}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.89259}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.89259}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq7}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Seq8}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & \textbf{0.80783} & 0.79928 & 0.80353 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.18731} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.18731} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.18731} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textbf{OURS} & 0.80603 & \textbf{0.80828} & \textbf{0.80715} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.62538}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.62538}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.62538}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq9}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Seq10}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.96184 & 0.95988 & 0.96086 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.88875} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.87596} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.88231} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textbf{OURS} & \textbf{0.99804} & \textbf{0.99609} & \textbf{0.99706} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.90537}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.90537}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.90537}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq11}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Seq12}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.00948 & 0.00474 & 0.00632 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.00000}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.00000}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.00000}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textbf{OURS} & \textbf{0.84360} & \textbf{0.84360} & \textbf{0.84360} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.00000}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.00000}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.00000}} \\
\newpage
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq13}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Seq14}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & \textbf{0.03131} & \textbf{0.03131} & \textbf{0.03131} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.08329} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.08329} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.08329} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \textbf{OURS} & 0.00196 & 0.00196 & 0.00196 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.08716}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.08716}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{0.08716}} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq15}} &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-4}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Prec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Rec}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{F1}} &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-4}    \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.85840 & 0.83793 & 0.84804 &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-4}    \textbf{OURS} & \textbf{0.85878} & \textbf{0.88959} & \textbf{0.87392} &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-4}    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Welcome, remove the `table` environment, substitute `tabular` with `longtable` and move the caption inside of that. Not tested, though.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I tried the suggestion but having an error: ! Misplaced \noalign.
\cmidrule ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@cmidrule }{\@cmidrule ...
l.106 \cmidrule
               {1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Seq1}} & ...

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a much simpler code, and a better-looking table, without vertical rule, using `siunitx` for numbers alignment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, hmargin=1.25in, ]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,  showframe}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,tabularx, longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.5, table-number-alignment=center,  detect-all}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet '(ALL)'
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\bfseries}lSSScSSS}%
  \caption{TESTING}
  \endfirsthead
  %\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{6-8}
  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq1}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq2}} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8} %
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &   & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textcolor{red}{R-GTC}           & 0.69527          & 0.67426          & 0.68460          &   & 0.90242          & 0.89107          & 0.89671          \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  OURS           & \textbf{0.75482} & \textbf{0.75482} & \textbf{0.75482} &   & \textbf{0.92057} & \textbf{0.91528} & \textbf{0.91792} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  \addlinespace
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq3}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq4}} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &   & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textcolor{red}{R-GTCG }         & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} &   & 0.61123          & 0.61019          & 0.61071          \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  OURS                             & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} &   & \textbf{0.81705} & \textbf{0.81705} & \textbf{0.81705} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  \addlinespace
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq5}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq6}} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &   & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.87119          & 0.84164          & 0.85616          &   & 0.88654          & 0.88654          & 0.88654          \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textbf{OURS}                    & \textbf{0.89381} & \textbf{0.89474} & \textbf{0.89427} &   & \textbf{0.89259} & \textbf{0.89259} & \textbf{0.89259} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  \addlinespace
  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq7}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq8}} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &   & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & \textbf{0.80783} & 0.79928          & 0.80353          &   & 0.18731          & 0.18731          & 0.18731          \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textbf{OURS}                    & 0.80603          & \textbf{0.80828} & \textbf{0.80715} &   & \textbf{0.62538} & \textbf{0.62538} & \textbf{0.62538} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  \addlinespace
  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq9}} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq10}} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &   & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.96184          & 0.95988          & 0.96086          &   & 0.88875          & 0.87596          & 0.88231          \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textbf{OURS}                    & \textbf{0.99804} & \textbf{0.99609} & \textbf{0.99706} &   & \textbf{0.90537} & \textbf{0.90537} & \textbf{0.90537} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  \addlinespace
  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq11}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq12}} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &   & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.00948          & 0.00474          & 0.00632          &   & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textbf{OURS}                    & \textbf{0.84360} & \textbf{0.84360} & \textbf{0.84360} &   & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  \addlinespace
  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq13}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq14}} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &   & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & \textbf{0.03131} & \textbf{0.03131} & \textbf{0.03131} &   & 0.08329          & 0.08329          & 0.08329          \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  \textbf{OURS}                    & 0.00196          & 0.00196          & 0.00196          &   & \textbf{0.08716} & \textbf{0.08716} & \textbf{0.08716} \\
  \cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-4}\cmidrule[1pt]{6-8}
  \addlinespace
  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq15}} & & & & \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}
  Method                           & \textbf{Prec}    & \textbf{Rec}     & \textbf{F1}      &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{R-GTCG}} & 0.85840          & 0.83793          & 0.84804          &               \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \textbf{OURS} & \textbf{0.85878} & \textbf{0.88959} & \textbf{0.87392} &    \\
  \cmidrule[1pt]{1-4}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mico and Bernard. Now with this, the tables fit perfectly well in a single page and I do not need \nextpage. Thank you all for the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The environments `table` and `tabular` *cannot* break across pages.

Change `\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|rrrr}` to `\begin{longtable}{l|r|r|r|rrrr}`, change `\end{tabular}` to `\end{longtable}`, move the `\caption` and `\label` statements inside the `longtable` environment, and delete the instructions `\begin{table}`, `\centering`, and `\end{table}`.

Separately, since you're using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, *don't use vertical bars*. No exceptions.

Finally, I'm afraid I have no way of breaking the following piece of information to you gently: Your code is awfully---and needlessly---complicated. For instance, *not a single one* of the multitude of `\multicolumn{1}{r|}{...}` "wrappers" appears to be needed. Do try to simplify your code, please.

---

Here's my take on how to improve the table. Observe: no vertical rules, fewer horizontal rules, more vertical whitespace, horizontal rules don't cover the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,booktabs,longtable,geometry,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}>{\bfseries}l rrr rrr@{}}
\caption{TESTING}\label{tab:addlabel}\\    
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq2}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & 0.69527 & 0.67426 & 0.68460 & 0.90242 & 0.89107 & 0.89671 \\
Ours & \textbf{0.75482} & \textbf{0.75482} & \textbf{0.75482} & \textbf{0.92057} & \textbf{0.91528} & \textbf{0.91792} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}   
\addlinespace 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq3}} & & \textbf{Seq4} &  \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & 0.61123 & 0.61019 & 0.61071 \\
Ours & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.74896} & \textbf{0.81705} & \textbf{0.81705} & \textbf{0.81705} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\addlinespace 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq5}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq6}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & 0.87119 & 0.84164 & 0.85616 & 0.88654 & 0.88654 & 0.88654 \\
Ours & \textbf{0.89381} & \textbf{0.89474} & \textbf{0.89427} & \textbf{0.89259} & \textbf{0.89259} & \textbf{0.89259} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\addlinespace 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq7}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq8}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & \textbf{0.80783} & 0.79928 & 0.80353 & 0.18731 & 0.18731 & 0.18731 \\
Ours & 0.80603 & \textbf{0.80828} & \textbf{0.80715} & \textbf{0.62538} & \textbf{0.62538} & \textbf{0.62538} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\addlinespace 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq9}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq10}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & 0.96184 & 0.95988 & 0.96086 & 0.88875 & 0.87596 & 0.88231 \\
Ours & \textbf{0.99804} & \textbf{0.99609} & \textbf{0.99706} & \textbf{0.90537} & \textbf{0.90537} & \textbf{0.90537} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\addlinespace 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq11}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq12}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & 0.00948 & 0.00474 & 0.00632 & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} \\
Ours & \textbf{0.84360} & \textbf{0.84360} & \textbf{0.84360} & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} & \textbf{0.00000} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\addlinespace 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq13}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq14}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & \textbf{0.03131} & \textbf{0.03131} & \textbf{0.03131} & 0.08329 & 0.08329 & 0.08329 \\
Ours & 0.00196 & 0.00196 & 0.00196 & \textbf{0.08716} & \textbf{0.08716} & \textbf{0.08716} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
\addlinespace 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Seq15}}   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}    
Method& \textbf{Prec} & \textbf{Rec} & \textbf{F1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}    
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{R-GTCG} & 0.85840 & 0.83793 & 0.84804 \\
Ours & \textbf{0.85878} & \textbf{0.88959} & \textbf{0.87392} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}    
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This `\multicolumn{1}{r|}{bla}` comes from the translation by Excel2LaTex, as far as I know it is produced when the size of the Excel-cell is non-standard.